# vue router forcing popstate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have some links in the middle of a page that changes the contents in the pane below it using a nested router. My routes conerned with this problem looks something like this:

```
const router = {
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/parent',
      name: 'ParentComponent',
      component: ParentComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'child1',
          name: 'Child1',
          component: Child1,
        },
        {
          path: 'child2',
          name: 'Child2',
          component: Child2,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

The issue is that the content is scrolled down the page and when I hit the link to the child path, it jumps to the top. So I tried to add `scrollBehavior` to maintain the scrolled position like so:

```
router.scrollBehavior = (to, from, savedPosition) => {
  console.log('savedPosition: ', savedPosition);
  if (savedPosition) {
    return savedPosition;
  }
  return { x: 0, y: 0 };
}
```

This `console.log` always outputs `null` for me. While reading the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#async-scrolling), it says that `savedPosition` only has a value if it is a `popstate` navigation.

Is there a way to force the links I've made to execute a `popstate` navigation or is there another approach I could use to preserve the scroll position for when I click the link?

Comment: Interestingly enough.. if I return `{}` instead of `savedPosition` the scroll maintains on navigation... i don't know why ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this recently

```
scrollBehavior (to, from) {
  if (to.path === from.path && to.query && to.query.page === from.query.page) {
    return false
  } else {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
},
```

That might get you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

It's just what is says in the linked [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#async-scrolling).

> The scrollBehavior function receives the to and from route objects.
>   The third argument, savedPosition, is only available if this is a
>   popstate navigation (triggered by the browser's back/forward buttons).

Since you are triggering the navigation using links in the middle of the page, it is not a pop state navigation.

So the correct course of action would be to just not use the savedPosition version of the function, because that position won't be set.